# wanna change status from 0 (unverified) to 1(verified) but my code doesnt work

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller

```
public function verifikasiTor($id_tor)
{
  $data['status'] = 0;
    if (!$this->m_tor->update_tor($id_tor, $data)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('gagal', "Gagal verifikasi TOR!");
        redirect('tor/dataTor');
    }
$this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', "Berhasil verifikasi TOR!");
redirect('tor/dataTor');
}
```

this is my model

```
public function update_tor($id_tor, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id_tor', $id_tor);
    $query = $this->db->update('tor', $data);
     return $query;
}
```

and this is my button

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verifikasi TOR" href="<?php echo base_url("tor/verifikasiTor/{$row->id_tor}") ?>">Verifikasi</a>
```

please help me, i'm new in codeigniter and i will appreciate your help.

Comment: make sure u have `$id_tor` in your controller and change status from `$data['status'] = '0';` to `$data['status'] = '1';` note the apostrophe for 0 and 1

Comment: @afranna........you can verified the answer if found it working...happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify then you need to set value 1 instead of 0 in array.

```
public function verifikasiTor($id_tor)
{
  $data['status'] = 1;
    if (!$this->m_tor->update_tor($id_tor, $data)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('gagal', "Gagal verifikasi TOR!");
        redirect('tor/dataTor');
    }
$this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', "Berhasil verifikasi TOR!");
redirect('tor/dataTor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `verifikasiTor` should be like this :

```
public function verifikasiTor($id_tor)
{
  if ( ! empty($id_tor))
  {
    $data['status'] = '1';
    /* Or for unverified should be $data['status'] = '0';*/
    if ($this->m_tor->update_tor($id_tor, $data)) 
    {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', "Berhasil verifikasi TOR!");
    }
    else
    {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('gagal', "Gagal verifikasi TOR!");
    }
    redirect('tor/dataTor');
  }  
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you for your response but it has been solved!